# Running commands in a loop without spawning a new subshell each time

Tags: linux, bash, performance, shell, subshell

I have a bash script that reads in lots of dates in epoch time, and determines the (local) hour of the day at which they occurred. Relevant snippet:

```
while read ts
do
  hour="$(date -d@$((${ts} / 1000)) +%H)"
  ((hourly_counts["${hour}"]+=1))
done < "${jqfile}"
```

It's rather slow, because it spawns a new subshell for each invocation of `date`. Is there a sensible way round this? It looks as though `date` doesn't support multiple queries.

All I can think of is to spawn a new shell, and pipe `date` commands to it and get the results back, so that they all execute in the same shell. But I'm not clear on how to do this, and it seems a little over-engineered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
printf -v hour '%(%H)T' "$(( ts / 1000 ))"
```

Type `help printf` to know more about the command.

Also check `strftime(3)`.  Behavior may depend on the value of `TZ` and `LC_TIME`.

Comment: Wow, that is very cool, I didn't know printf could handle timestamps!

Comment: I'm still interested to know if there's a solution to the more general problem, though (not specific to `date`, but just needing to run lots of commands without spawning a subshell for each).

Comment: @chiastic-security For that, I think your original idea sounds pretty good. I've used that technique when I needed to speed up commands sent to an interpreter (`cleartool` in that case) and it helped a lot. You could perhaps set the prompt to `PS1='\n[$?] ~~~~delimiter~~~~\n'` to make it easy to parse when the output from the previous command is done (and what exit status it had.